# Fetch Contact Image - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, cncontact, cncontactstore

I'm trying to fetch the image property of a given `contact`. Here's what I got:

**Model**

```
struct Contact: Identifiable {
    let contact: CNContact

    var id: String { contact.identifier }
    var image: Data? { contact.imageData }
    var givenName: String { contact.givenName }
}

static func fetch(_ completion: @escaping(Result<[Contact], Error>) -> Void) {
    let containerID = CNContactStore().defaultContainerIdentifier
    let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: containerID())
        
    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactImageDataKey,
        CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
        CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,
        CNContactGivenNameKey,
        CNContactFamilyNameKey,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
        CNContactEmailAddressesKey
     ] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
        
     do {
        let contacts = try CNContactStore().unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
        completion(.success(contacts.map({ .init(contact: $0)})))
     } catch {
        completion(.failure(error))
     }
}
```

**View**

```
struct ContactRow: View {
    let contact: Contact
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(String(describing: contact.image))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .background(AppColor())
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                
                Text(contact.givenName)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1)))

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The error(s) I get are purple, and say

> *runtime: SwiftUI: No image named 'Optional(38321 bytes)' found in asset catalog for /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/* ...etc

Obviously I have contact images in my `Contacts` app Apple provides.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your contact image is `Data`, so you should create `Image` in different way, like

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: contact.image ?? Data()) ?? UIImage())
```