# How to get and display contact photos on iOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a running script to read and display all contacts on iOS with SwiftUI but I am struggling to show the contact images as well. When I debug the code, imageData seems empty for all contacts and hasImageData is false. Generally the contacts are synchronized from Google to the iPhone, but for test purpose I have added photos on the iPhone to some contacts with the same result - no result.

Hopefully anybody have a clue what's going wrong :-)

---

```
import SwiftUI
import Contacts

struct FetchedContact {
    var id: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var telephone: String
}

func getContacts() -> [FetchedContact] {
    
    var contacts = [FetchedContact]()
    
    let store = CNContactStore()
    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("failed to request access", error)
            return
        }
        if granted {
            let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
            let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
            do {
                try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointer) in
                    contacts.append(FetchedContact(id: contact.identifier, firstName: contact.givenName, lastName: contact.familyName, telephone: contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""))
                })
            } catch let error {
                print("Failed to enumerate contact", error)
            }
        } else {
            print("access denied")
        }
        
    }
    
    contacts.sort {
        $0.firstName < $1.firstName
    }
    
    contacts.sort {
        $0.lastName < $1.lastName
    }
    
    return contacts
    
}

struct ContactListView: View {
    
    @State var contacts = [FetchedContact]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.contacts = getContacts()
            }) {
                Text("Update contacts")
            }
            .padding()
            Text("\(self.contacts.count) contacts found")
                .padding()
            List(self.contacts, id: \.id) { contact in
                Text("\(contact.lastName), \(contact.firstName)")
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Contact List View")
    }
    
}

struct ContactListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            ContactListView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64510100/fetch-contact-image-swiftui?

Comment: Yes, in fact I missed to add the corresponding keys to the request - thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Add required keys to the query

   let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey]
2. Modify the image display

   Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: contact.image ?? Data()) ?? UIImage())